# What version of Wildfly and undertow that comes with JBoss EAP 7.4?

Tags: jboss, wildfly, undertow

I couldn't see much on the Jboss documentation. Can I use wildfly version 26.0.1 and undertow 2.2.14. Or is there a better match for Jboss 7.4?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redhat lists [components](https://access.redhat.com/articles/112673) for JBoss EAP 7.4 as:

Undertow    2.2.5.Final

Wildfly Core    15.0.2.Final

Is that what you are looking for?

Answer (score 4):

## TL;DR

If you need the application server, it is:
WildFly 23

If you need artifacts, this is for JBoss EAP 7.4.5:
Undertow 2.2.17.SP4-redhat-00001
WildFly Core 15.0.13.Final-redhat-00001

There is also a runtime BOM for the artifacts delivered with JBoss EAP.
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.bom/eap-runtime-artifacts

## Long version

As [Doug Grove](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70929206/10252140)
already described, there is an [article in the Red Hat Knowledgebase](https://access.redhat.com/articles/112673) that lists the different JBoss EAP versions with the integrated components. However, starting from JBoss EAP 7.x, the component versions of only *one* non-described JBoss EAP patch version are listed per JBoss EAP minor version.

For JBoss EAP 7.4, the article states (as of 06/22/2022):
Undertow 2.2.5.Final
WildFly Core 15.0.2.Final

If you want to have the versions for all shipped artifacts of a specific JBoss EAP patch, Red Hat offers a Maven BOM file:
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.bom/eap-runtime-artifacts

For JBoss EAP 7.4.5, it states:
Undertow 2.2.17.SP4-redhat-00001
WildFly Core 15.0.13.Final-redhat-00001
(Red Hat specific versions from the Redhat GA repository)

However, it is important to note, that the listed WildFly Core version is not the same as the WildFly application server version. If you compare the version of WildFly Core used in the WildFly 23 Undertow artifact with the one in the JBoss EAP Runtime BOM, you will notice that JBoss EAP 7.4 uses the same Core as WildFly 23 application server.
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.wildfly/wildfly-undertow/23.0.2.Final

Or see the POM file of WildFly 23:
https://github.com/wildfly/wildfly/blob/23.0.0.Final/pom.xml#L473

Therefore JBoss EAP 7.4 corresponds roughly to WildFly 23.