# JBoss EAP 7.4 and Keycloak

Tags: jboss, keycloak, openid-connect

I am trying to make JBoss authenticate users based on OpenID Connect and Keycloak. I was able to setup Wildfly 26 to get it right - but JBoss EAP 7.4 (the currently latest version) is different.

The adapters on http://keycloak.org are all marked as deprecated, yet JBoss EAP 7.4 seems to support authentication over OAuth2 out of the box:
https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/7.4/html-single/how_to_configure_identity_management/index#configuring-oauth2-bearer-tokens-elytron

From the puzzle part examples given i seem unable to complete the picture. How would a working configuration look like?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this [blog post](https://wildfly-security.github.io/wildfly-elytron/blog/securing-wildfly-apps-openid-connect/) will help . It explains how to secure an application deployed to WildFly with OIDC without needing to use the Keycloak adapter. There is also a linked [example project](https://github.com/wildfly-security-incubator/elytron-examples/tree/main/simple-webapp-oidc).

Comment: The post contains 'WildFly 25 introduced...', this is exactly how I made Wildfly 26 work. It does not apply to JBoss EAP 7.4, which is based on Wildfly 23. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70922164/what-version-of-wildfly-and-undertow-that-comes-with-jboss-eap-7-4